# Visual Studio Team Services No Build Artifacts Created

Tags: build, msbuild, azure-devops, definition

I use an onsite build agent to perform my **VSTS builds**. This is working fine, sort of. I have 2 build definitions, one of which is a clone of the other and the only difference between the 2 is the solution that is built, all other parameters are exactly the same.

One of my builds completes without error and creates build artifacts and compiled code zip files in the 'build/1/a' artifacts folder. My other build completes without error BUT there are no build artifacts and compiled zip files created, my 'build/3/a' directory for this build is empty and I cannot see anywhere in the logs where the tasks to create this was executed, if at all. This did used to work before I cloned the build definition though. These are the MSBuild arguments that I have defined for both build definitions;

`/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:PackageTempRootDir="D:\Build\SiteManagerDev"`

The only difference between them is the last parameter `'/p:PackageTempRootDir'.`

I have tried switching between the 2 directories for both build definitions to make sure it is not a permission error and the definition that finishes correctly works against either directory. I am starting to tear my hair out now and I have even tried creating a completely new build definition for the solution that creates an incomplete build and it is the same result, it is almost as if it is the solution itself that is causing the issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE: 05/02/2017**

I think I finally understand what is going on! Question, if a build is manually triggered, not by a check-in trigger, if there have been no changes made to the code, and even though the build is executed, does this prevent the build artifacts from being created again because nothing has changed? The reason I ask is because I have found a strange in-house housekeeping routine that goes and deletes the contents of the 'D:\Build\1\a' directory on our build machine on a regular basis (I have no idea why!) and this results in there being nothing to publish UNTIL there is a code change checked in and then they are generated again! What a waste of everyone time this has been, my apologies and thank you for your help.

Comment: Set the variable system.debug=true in your build definition, and post the logs of your build task output.  We can't do much other than speculate at this point.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, there are quite a few relatively large .txt files created. Is there a specific I need to post or do you need all of them?

Comment: you don't have to post them, but your answer should be in there somewhere.  Like you said the "/a" folder is not being populated.  The reason why should be in those logs somewhere.

Comment: Could it be related to this line in the log? "Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files."

Comment: I also see this line in the log "##[warning]Directory 'D:\Build\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact" I am really lost and cannot understand why no artifacts are being created?

Comment: @Reggie Can you provide the logs for Visual Studio Build tasks of your two build definitions separately? And what's the differences for the solutions in the two build definitions?